# LG Stylo 3 on Cricket, Wi-Fi randomly disconnecting

Tags: wi-fi

I got an LG Stylo 3 on Cricket last month, and already I seem to have a problem. Randomly, it will disconnect from Wi-Fi. When I go into the settings, it'll say that the network is disabled.

Any idea what could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems, did all advice given, but this one thing I did helped.

1. Go to Settings
2. Click on Wi-Fi
3. Click on Wi-Fi Manager
4. Click on box if checkmark on

Now it connects and stays connected, at home and everywhere else.

Comment: I followed your instructions and it still disconnects

Answer (score 0):

From [OP's (now deleted) comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/196737/lg-stylo-3-wi-fi-randomly-disconnecting#comment281692_196737),

> The problem got solved. I turned off Cricket Wi-Fi Manager as [Jess in the replies](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/199908/44325) said, then in Advanced Wi-Fi, turned off "Switch to mobile data."